# How do you delete the Apple ID of a dead person?

Tags: apple-id

I need to delete the Apple ID of my dads iPad. He died and I don't know his password.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the only way to remove an iCloud password is to contact Apple with the relevant documentation.

This link has some contact details

https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204169

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete an account without having the Apple ID and password. Apple has updated its privacy policy since the incident with FaceBook took place.

But if you want to transfer the account call Apple Support. You'll need the death certificate and a court document that confirms that you are the decedent's legal personal representative. That document needs to be notarized or certified by a US court.

If you just want to remove the account from the iPad, if you have a receipt or invoice from where the device was purchased with the devices serial/IMEI number along with the sellers location, and contact info then the FindMyiPhone team at Apple Support can remove the account from the iPad.

If you can't do either, then at least call in and get help with recovering the password by calling in. Worst case scenario, it'll put you in account recovery in which after waiting a period of time, you'll get access to the account.

Comment: I should just add that in the case of *other* jurisdictions, documents would not need to be notarised or certified by a US court. Instead they will need to meet Apple's requirements for that jurisdiction.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I'll state that this applies to USA and Canadian residents.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has provided an online system to delete Apple IDs in such a case.

Visit http://digital-legacy.apple.com

You will need

- The Apple ID of the deceased (but you do not need the password)
- The "Letters of Appointment" as the personal representative of the
  deceased, typically provided in the United States by the County court after filing a request to be appointed per the decedant's Will (a probate lawyer can file this for you), and
- the death certificate.

Peace be with you.